# Rotating outgoing IP's

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, web-server, routing

I want to rotate IP addresses for web-scraping, and here is my setup:

1. I have configured multiple IP addresses as below in  my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

   ```
   # The loopback network interface
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

   # The primary network interface
   allow-hotplug eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
       address XX.XXX.XXX.146
       netmask 255.255.255.248
       network XX.XXX.XXX.144
       broadcast XX.XXX.XXX.151
       gateway XX.XXX.XXX.145
       # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
       dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220
       dns-search host.myhost.com
   auto eth0:1
   iface eth0:1 inet static
   address XX.XXX.XXX.147
   netmask 255.255.255.248
   broadcast XX.XXX.XXX.151 
   network XX.XXX.XXX.144 

   auto eth0:2
   iface eth0:2 inet static
   address XX.XXX.XXX.148
   netmask 255.255.255.248
   broadcast XX.XXX.XXX.151 
   network XX.XXX.XXX.144 

   auto eth0:3
   iface eth0:3 inet static
   address XX.XXX.XXX.149
   netmask 255.255.255.248
   broadcast XX.XXX.XXX.151 
   network XX.XXX.XXX.144
   ```
2. Cloudflare DNS performs the round-robin to different IP addresses of my server.
3. However, when I use the following PHP script to check my external IP address, I get different values for `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];` but my external IP address remains same (as checked by the script below from `http://checkip.dyndns.com/`).

   ```
   <?php
   $externalContent = file_get_contents('http://checkip.dyndns.com/');
   preg_match('/Current IP Address: ([\[\]:.[0-9a-fA-F]+)</', $externalContent, $m);
   $externalIp = $m[1];
   echo $externalIp;
   echo '<br/>';
   echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
   ?>
   ```

What am I missing here, I want to execute an external executable which should use different public IP addresses available on  my server in rotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out, the solution is to configure `iptables` rules as below:

`iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 1 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source XX.XXX.XXX.146
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source XX.XXX.XXX.147
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 3 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source XX.XXX.XXX.148
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -o eth0 -m statistic --mode nth --every 4 --packet 0 -j SNAT --to-source XX.XXX.XXX.149`

Comment: That is an interesting solution to your problem!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use different source IP addresses when using the file_get_contents PHP function, you should try using PHP [contexts](http://php.net/manual/en/context.php) and specifying the [bindto](http://php.net/manual/it/context.socket.php) socket option.

If you're NOT using PHP and your client connection does not provide an option to bind to a specific source address, then you nave no other chance than iptables source-nat: you can define proper iptables [nat translations](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-6.html) for each of your outgoing IP addresses.

Please note that DNS does NOT nave any role for what you need, as it relates only to INBOUND services.

Comment: I am confused, I am launching an executable from my PHP script and want that to use different ip's available on my server to make connections to the external website.

Comment: @iTech: I've slightly rephrase my answer.

Comment: Thanks, already figured and shared it as another answer above.